# How can I get PyCharm to recognize the static files?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have one Django project that looks like:

```
/.idea
/clients
     /app
         /static
             coin.png
         /templates
             index.html
         __init__.py
         urls.py
     /clients
         settings.py
     manage.py
```

In index.html I have (I can see the image on render):

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<img src="{% static 'coin.png' %}">
```

Relevant parts of settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../static/'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
)
```

In project structure I've added `/clients` since the root of the Django project is one level up from the repo root. However all my `{% static %}` uses in this project keep getting highlights as not existing even though Django can find them. Ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: How is STATIC_ROOT defined in your settings.py?

Comment: @yole I've added relevant parts to the question.

Comment: @yole same problem with `STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'assets'))`. Has PyCharm some hacks for manual settings static dir? PyCharm EAP 129.782, django 1.5.1

Comment: @b1 http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10194

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set the following settings, to tell PyCharm where to find the project root:

[image]

[Django settings to set (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byRX8.png)

You can also use {{STATIC_URL}}/path/to/files, which works different by pycharm

This worked wonders. It is a bit strange of pycharm though.

Answer (score 12):

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'static',
)
```

The above assumes that your static dir is called `static` right under your root. Now need to do `os.path.join`. I've tried and tested this.

Comment: The thing is that OP has `static` directory inside and app, and probably inside several more apps too. This is perfectly valid pattern for static files in Django - that is what the second default finder does! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_FINDERS PyCharm should really parse this, at least for default settings, IMO. cc @KitSunde

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you!